# Get data from two tables using UNION ALL

Tags: mysql, union

I have three tables: categories and deals1 and deals2.

I have the next mySQL sentence and it works:

```
SELECT name,
(SELECT categoria FROM categorias WHERE categorias.id = deals.id) AS categoria 
from deals1 where id = '1'
```

But now, I need to use UNION ALL to get the datas from two diferent tables... Something like this:

```
(SELECT name,
(SELECT categoria FROM categorias WHERE categorias.id = deals1.id) AS categoria 
from deals1 where id = '1')

UNION ALL

(SELECT name,
(SELECT categoria FROM categorias WHERE categorias.id = deals2.id) AS categoria 
from deals2 where id = '1')
```

It return an error.... ¿what the correct way to get the union data?

Thanks so much!

---

EDITED:
I found the problem...

In my project I had:

```
... SELECT categoria FROM categorias WHERE categorias.id = **deals2.id**) AS categoria 
from **deals1** where id = '1')
```

The next is the correct sentence... If you pay atention, you will see the diferences (strong words)...

```
(SELECT name,
(SELECT categoria FROM categorias WHERE categorias.id = **deals2.id**) AS categoria 
from **deals2** where id = '1')
```

Thanks to all!

Comment: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Answer (score 1):

The syntax looks correct , the only thing that bothers me is the parenthesis:

The syntax for my queries was always:

```
SELECT name,
(SELECT categoria FROM categorias WHERE categorias.id = deals1.id) AS categoria 
from deals1 where id = '1'

UNION ALL

SELECT name,
(SELECT categoria FROM categorias WHERE categorias.id = deals2.id) AS categoria 
from deals2 where id = '1';
```

without the external parenthesis...
please note - the table in the subselect should be deals1 / deals2 - not deals.

But - what is the error you're getting?

Also - do you want to use union all or union (do you want same result to appears once , or multiple times)? union would also add an implicit "distinct" which by the phrasing - I think you expect, but I am not sure about it (union all would just concatenate the results, when results would repeat if same record was produced)

Comment: I dont want to exclude repeat records, this is why I use UNION ALL. The error I'm getting is:

Custom error: [2] mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Comment: Note what I just fixed. Does the categorias.id is a primary key? is deals1/deals2.id is an FK to the table, and is also not null? the problem before the last change was that the subselect produced no/more than 1 results (since it joined the wrong source table). after the last change make sure that for each deals1/2.id there's a matching record in caategorias table.

Comment: I foud the problem... See the post. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First check table names, you are saying its deals1 and deals2, however in union all first query

```
(SELECT name,
(SELECT categoria FROM categorias WHERE categorias.id = deals.id) AS categoria 
from deals where id = '1')
```

its "deals".

Comment: check the query in mysql and see if it is retuning result or not.

Comment: I foud the problem... See the post. Thank you!